# How to convert mounted filesystem between codepages?

Tags: filesystems, conversion, character-encoding

I have an external drive formatted in `ext3` (basically) that previously was connected to a Linksys NLSU2 NAS device. Now the NSLU2 is broken and I have struggled to restore the files on the disk because its filenames are using a Windows codepage (`cp850`). I can access the disk through a tool called "ext2fsd" in Windows where I have the option of choosing the proper codepage. However, my Windows computer is rather old and the ext2fsd tool is crashing from time to time.

When i try to mount the disk in Ubuntu I get broken filenames because the codepage is non-standard, I presume. Is it possible to:

1. Mount the drive in Ubuntu as ext3 with the codepage used on the disk?
2. **Convert** the codepage to a standard one suitable for ext3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to fix the filenames with `convmv` - not sure if it's available for Windows, Ubuntu has it in repositories. This is a tool I've used for this exact use case. From its [manual](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/):

> convmv is meant to help convert a single filename, a directory tree and the contained files or a whole filesystem into a different encoding. It just converts the filenames, not the content of the files. A special feature of convmv is that it also takes care of symlinks, also converts the symlink target pointer in case the symlink target is being converted, too.
>
> All this comes in very handy when one wants to switch over from old 8-bit locales to UTF-8 locales. It is also possible to convert directories to UTF-8 which are already partly UTF-8 encoded. convmv is able to detect if certain files are UTF-8 encoded and will skip them by default. To turn this smartness off use the --nosmart switch.